# what rules does SQL Server use to determine which column/columns will the phantom clustered index be created on?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

[The Definitive Guide to Scaling out SQL Server 2005](http://www.snip.gob.ni/Xdc/SQL/DGSOSSFinal.pdf):

> if you create a nonclustered index and don’t already have a clustered
>   index, SQL Server creates a  “phantom” clustered index because
>   nonclustered indexes always point to clustered index keys.

1. What rules does SQL Server use to determine which column/columns will the phantom clustered index be created on?
2. If it is on the primary key of that table (quick guess), what rules does SQL Server use to determine which column/columns will the phantom clustered index be created on for a table without primary keys?

(question targeted at any version of SQL Server 2005 and beyond)

Comment: I'd say the source you're quoting is simply incorrect. Non clustered indexes against a heap table, at the leaves, store [row pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx). Non clustered indexes against a clustered table, at the leaves, store the clustered index.

Comment: could you supply some links backing your argument. because i do not think http://www.snip.gob.ni/Xdc/SQL/DGSOSSFinal.pdf is incorrect

Comment: I included a link to the Microsoft documentation in my first comment. And (snide comment ahead) I know I can stop reading your source, because it says "... SQL Server 2000 offers a great GUI, in the form of Enterprise Manager ...". If you want real info on the internals of SQL Server's data structures, a book such as [this](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=7436&locale=en-us) might be what you need.

Comment: I second Damien's comments. There is no such thing as a "phantom" clustered index. Anyway the DGSOSSFinal.pdf document appears to cover only SQL Server 2000 so you can disregard it if you are interested in 2005 and beyond.

Comment: @Damien i do not think you can base a source just on that info. after all "great" is a subjective word. the great 10 yrs ago and the great now is 2 different words altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a primary key, SSMS will by default make that the clustered index. But if you specifically create a table without a clustered index, you are creating a heap table. SQL Server uses an internal value for referencing rows, but it is not any of your columns. The following may help:

[On a Heap Table, what does a non-clustered index use as a pointer to a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454127/on-a-heap-table-what-does-a-non-clustered-index-use-as-a-pointer-to-a-row)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964133%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1254

Answer (score 1):

The quote you are providing is wrong. You might want to read a high quality book, such as a book by Kalen Delaney: http://www.sqlserverinternals.com/books.html